# SQL Having statement with Date Range - The grouping is inconsistent

Tags: sql, db2

I'm struggling with this script.  I want to write it where it'll calculate the total of instances then add the sum of those instances, however, when I run the script with the "HAVING....AND CSH.SLS_DT BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2015-06-16'" I get an error stating that ***"the grouping is inconsistent"***.

The script runs fine when I comment out the date range, but the date range is critical to this script.  Thank you in advance for your help.  Script is below:

```
SELECT OS.STR_NBR STORE                           
        , CSH.CSHR_USER_ID LDAP                    
        , COUNT(CSH.USER_ID) AS COUNT              
        , SUM(OS.OVR_SHRT_AMT) AS TOTAL            

 FROM PRHDW.VLT_CSHR_AUD CSH                       

 LEFT OUTER 
 JOIN PRHDW.VLT_AUD_OVR_SHRT OS                    
      ON     OS.STR_NBR = CSH.STR_NBR              
      AND    OS.SLS_DT = CSH.SLS_DT                
      AND    OS.CSHR_SYSUSR_ID = CSH.CSHR_SYSUSR_ID

 GROUP BY    OS.STR_NBR, CSH.CSHR_USER_ID          

 HAVING             OS.STR_NBR       = '0121'             
          --AND     SUM (OS.OVR_SHRT_AMT) > 0         
            AND     CSH.SLS_DT BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-16'  
  ORDER BY TOTAL DESC                                             
  WITH UR;
```

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is applied after `GROUP BY`, at which point `CSH.SLS_DT` is _not_ available -- `HAVING` can only operate on what is in the `SELECT` list (or an aggregate function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your constraints it should work fine with a where clause. The intention of the having clause is to compare to some aggregate. Obviously you aren't doing that so 
should read as follows:

```
AND    OS.CSHR_SYSUSR_ID = CSH.CSHR_SYSUSR_ID 
WHERE OS.STR_NBR = '0121' 
AND     CSH.SLS_DT BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-16'
GROUP BY OS.STR_NBR, CSH.CSHR_USER_ID
```

Comment: This will fix the syntax problem.  It is unclear if it is the logic the OP intends.